# Navigate in multiple sheet in VBA depending on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am a fairly new VBA user and have doing few codes learning as I go and reading forums.

Now I want to code something and I couldn't find a way to do it/a hint in the forums so I am coming to ask for your kind help.

I have a lot of spreadsheet with names as title, representing expenses of those people. My goal is to create a file in which I regroup the spreadsheets, then would like to extract the expense references in the "Home" spreadsheet. The relevant expanses will be marked "Y" in the same row.

In the "Home" spreadsheet I have names of people on the first page e.g. "Paul", "Marie","Pierre" etc.... in the same column.

I would like to create a code that could look at the names in the spreadsheet "Home" and copy data from the "Named" Spreadsheet back to the "Home" one.

Format would be the same for the "Named spreadsheet" so I am always looking at the same column.

I have tried the following so far

```
Sub Expenses()

    Set wk=ThisWorkbok.sheets("Home")

    Dim Name as String
    Dim Expense as Integer
    line_newexpense = 9
    rowline = 10
    start_l =34

    Do While Name <> "#"
        Line = wk.Cells(start_l,3)
        Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Cells(line_newexpense,39).Value
        Expense = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Name).Cells(rowline,3).Value

        For j=50 to 8
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Name).Cells(25,j).Value="Y" Then
                Line = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Name).Cells(3,j).Value
            End If
            rowline = rowline+1
        Next j

        line_newexpense = line_newexpense + 1
    Loop
```

The problem is when I try to run it I encounter an "Error 9 Subscript out of range", so not sure how I could counter the problem,

Many thanks in advance for your hints!

Kind Regards,

Comment: Hi Carolina, welcome to Stack Overflow. I have edited your question to make your code more readable.  Well indented code generally attracts better quality answers. Good luck!

Comment: Hey Carolina, when you `Set wk=ThisWorkbok.sheets("Home")` workbook is misspelled, which means that you cannot access `Line = wk.Cells(start_l,3)` as wk is not set. Then when you try to iterate j from 50 to 8, you need to specify that j will be j - 1 like this : `For j=50 to 8 step-1`, but with this j will go backward and rowline will go forward.

Comment: please add screenshots of "Home" and "Name" sheets

Comment: @user3598756 Never ask for screenshost, unless it is an UI question. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316945/is-please-post-a-picture-a-non-constructive-comment).

Comment: Carolina: then post files! @vacip: anyhow I was not asking for code in screenshot!

Comment: Thanks @Miguel_Ryu for spotting the tipo, but unfortunately still doesn't work for me, they have located the mistake on the "Expense" line... Apparently VBA doesn't like me using ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Name)...
Happy to post some screenshots (not sure I can the post the files) if you want to better understand the structure!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need VBA for this. You can use `INDIRECT` function to achieve what you want.

For example

```
=INDIRECT(B1&"!$A$1")
```

Where `B1` has the name of the worksheet, Say "Paul" and `A1` is the cell which has the data that you need.

[image]

You can also factor the `Y` part in your above formula using `IF` function.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and the help!
Have tried to implement the changes but would like the extract on my front page to be one line after the other, I am not sure that indirect represents the best option for that. I wanted to use VBA as it allows for flexibility and formatting, but if indirect gets me there happy to learn the trick (e.g.: having three line of expenses but I want the #1 and #3 to appear on the "Home" Sheet one below the other, how can I do that? Thanks!